# Working with Java String and ResultSet Object Dynamically

Tags: java, resultset

I would like to fetch data from Database Table A and create an insert statement to load Table B.
To preserving the data type, I am creating a one Time statament using the ResultSet methods to read from table A as shown below.

> Insert into table values
>   (rs.getString(1),rs.getInt(3),rs.getString(5),rs.getInt(6),rs.getString(7),rs.getInt(8),rs.getString(9),rs.getInt(10),rs.getString(11),rs.getInt(13),rs.getString(16))

My next step would be iterating over the records from Table A and sending these insert statements as BATCH to TABLE B. But how do I replace the Strings `(rs.getString(1) and rs.getInt(3) ... )` with actual values while looping on `rs.next()` .

Answer (score 1):

You need to create `PreparedStatement` for insert like this using placeholders:

```
PreparedStatement insert = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO TABLE_B VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
while (rs.next()) {
  insert.setString(1, rs.getString(1)); 
  insert.setInt(2, rs.getInt(3));   
  insert.setString(3, rs.getString(5));  
  insert.setInt(4, rs.getInt(6)); 
  insert.setString(5, rs.getString(7)); 
  insert.setInt(6, rs.getInt(8)); 
  insert.setString(7, rs.getString(9)); 
  insert.setInt(8, rs.getInt(10)); 
  insert.setString(9, rs.getString(11));
  insert.setInt(10, rs.getInt(13)); 
  insert.setString(11, rs.getString(16));
  insert.addBatch();
  // call insert.executeBatch() once you accumulate enough records for insert
}
```

If types of columns in target table match types of columns used from source table you could use `ResultSetMetaData` to set parameters in `PreparedStatement`

```
  ResultSetMetaData md = rs.getMetaData();
  while (rs.next()) {
  for (int m = 1; m <= md.getColumnCount(); m++) {
            if (rs.getObject(m) == null) {
                targetStatement.setNull(m, md.getColumnType(m));
            } else if (md.getColumnType(m) == OracleTypes.VARCHAR) {
                targetStatement.setString(m, rs.getString(m));
            } else if (md.getColumnType(m) == OracleTypes.NUMBER) {
                targetStatement.setDouble(m, rs.getDouble(m));
            } else if (md.getColumnType(m) == OracleTypes.CHAR) {
                targetStatement.setString(m, rs.getString(m));
            } else if (md.getColumnType(m) == OracleTypes.TIMESTAMP) {
                targetStatement.setTimestamp(m, rs.getTimestamp(m));
            } else if (md.getColumnType(m) == OracleTypes.DATE) {
                targetStatement.setDate(m, rs.getDate(m));
            } else {
                targetStatement.setString(m, rs.getString(m));
            }
  }
  insert.addBatch();
  // call insert.executeBatch() once you accumulate enough records for insert
}
```

Comment: Glad to see your response. I have write a generalised code rather than hardcoding as the table Names would be passed as paramter. Diff tables may contain diff no of cols.

Comment: Updated with usage of `ResultSetMetaData` to make it easier to construct `PreparedStatement`. But in this case your SELECT statement from source table should have the same columns as INSERT into target table. And you might need a wrapper class which will generate you different `PreparedStatement`s based on source table name.

Answer (score 1):

Try to do all in a single statement first.

```
INSERT INTO xtable (x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9, x10, x11)
(SELECT y1, y3, y5, y6, y7, y8, y9, y10, y11, y13, y16
 FROM ytable
 WHERE ...)
```

Otherwise use the PreparedStatement as of @Ivan.

Comment: Thanks Joop. Yeah Thinking of using preparedStatement though it invloves lot of iterations over no of records.

Answer (score 0):

```
String template = "Insert into TABLE_B values(\"{0}\", {1}, \"{2}\", {3}, \"{4}\", {5}, \"{6}\", {7}, \"{8}\", {9}, \"{10}\")";
MessageFormat mf = new MessageFormat(template);
while (rs.next()}
   Object[] params = new Object[11];
   params[0] = rs.getString(1);
   params[1] = rs.getInt(3);
   params[2] = rs.getString(5);
   params[3] = rs.getInt(6);
   params[4] = rs.getString(7);
   params[5] = rs.getInt(8);
   params[6] = rs.getString(9);
   params[7] = rs.getInt(10);
   params[8] = rs.getString(11);
   params[9] = rs.getInt(13);
   params[10] = rs.getString(16);

   String command = mf.format(params);
   //do with command what ever want to do
}
```

Bu why to bother when you can do insert from table to table with one SQL command: [INSERT INTO...SELECT](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp)

Comment: Thanks Mark. They reside in two diff database